# Author e-mail in title page in revtex4-1

Tags: revtex

I am using revtex4-1 with the following document class

```
\documentclass[prb,aps,twocolumn,longbibliography, linenumbers,amsmath,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4-1}
```

With this setting, the author e-mail address appears in the bibliography.

```
\author{Albert Einstein}
\email{einstein13@gmail.com}
\affiliation{Swiss patent office}
```

How can I make it appear on the title page as a footnote?

Comment: Can you please make a full (minimal) example?

Answer (score 0):

Keep both superscript citation styles and the author's email (and notes) on the first page

```
\documentclass[prb,nobibnotes]{revtex4-1}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, could you possibly make a full example out of this?